# Математические действия с уникальными значениями в группах

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: .]

Добрый день.

Сделала срез по пользователям из группы 247, выполнивших событие MainScreenAppear-2482 человека.

Всего у меня 3 группы и 7551 уникальный пользователь в датасете log. Нужно найти долю совершивших действие, то есть поделить 2482 на 7551. Ответ внизу получается неверный.

Спасибо каждому

Comment: ну так вам нужно число на число поделить. зачем же вы делите датафрейм на датафрейм? сделайте переменную (не столбец фрейма) `user_unique = log['user_id'].nunique()`.

Comment: Есть ли другой способ, помимо обычного деления числа на число?

Comment: вам не нужен другой способ. вам нужно разделить число на число, а не серию на серию. я вам уже написал - получите число в переменную, а потом разделите group_2.iloc[1,1] (или где там у вас уникальные юзер-ид) на это число.